# VS Code cant find references to some Unity Classes

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, package

So, i just upgraded my Visual Studio Code Package from 1.2.3 to 1.2.4 and then it cant find the references to Cinemachine, UI and TextMeshPro anymore. With any other code editor it works well, even with Visual Studio 2019.I'm using Unity 2021.1.3f, and i cant find were to downgrade the version of the VS Code package.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so i found a solution, but its kinda weird and i hope they fix it by the next unity update.

for Unity 2021.1.3f1
First you need to create another Unity project. The VS Code package already come in the 1.2.3 version from default.

Close Unity after the project is created.

After that you need to copy the "Assets" folder and the "Project Settings" folder to your new project. Unfortunatly you have to manually install any package that you project depends on manually (Because i dont know how to copy/paste any package from one project to another) and after that dont update the VS Code package again.

I higly recomend creating a copy of your project (or having it in a git repository) before updating any package because Unity dont let you downgrade packages anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Unity Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html) window (in Unity’s top menu: Window > Package Manager) to view which packages are available for installation or already installed in your project. In addition, you can use this window to install, remove, or update packages for each project.

[image]

Comment: The Visual Studio Code Package is already instaled and TMPro and Cinemachine are installed too. The problem is that,since i installed the new version, VS code couldnt find some of the packages of Unity, such as UI, Cinemachine and TextMeshPro.